# Compilation error with bresenham line algorithm?

Tags: c, opengl

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int x0,y0,xn,yn;

void bresenham(void)
{
    int dx,dy,m,pk,xk,yk,k;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    setPixel(x0,y0);
    dx=xn-x0;
    dy=yn-y0;
    pk=2*dy-dx;
    m=dy/dx;
    xk=x0;
    yk=y0;
    if(m>0 && m<1)
    {
        for(k=0;k<dx-1;k++)
        {
            if(pk<0)
            {
                xk++;
                pk=pk+2*dy;
            }
            else
            {
                xk++;
                yk++;
                pk=pk+2*dy-2*dx;
            }
            setPixel(xk,yk);
        }
    }
    glFlush();
}

int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    printf("enter starting points");
    scanf("%d",&x0);
    scanf("%d",&y0);
    printf("enter endpoints");
    scanf("%d",&xn);
    scanf("%d",&yn);
    glutInit(&argc,argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,25);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,250);
    glutCreateWindow("Bresenham Line");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(bresenham);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,400.0,0.0,400.0);
} 

void setPixel(GLint x,GLint y)
{
    glColor3f(255,255,255);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(x,y);
    glEnd();
}
```

the error is:

> 4 8   C:\Users\Hewlett\Documents\bresenham1.c [Error] 'y0' redeclared as
>   different kind of symbol
>   ,4    14  C:\Users\Hewlett\Documents\bresenham1.c [Error] 'yn' redeclared
>   as different kind of symbol .

Can anyone tell why it is showing y0 &yn are redeclared as different kind of symbol

Answer (score 1):

> why it is showing y0 &yn are redeclared as different kind of symbol

Because [you are:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/y0.html)

> The y0(), y1(), and yn() functions shall compute [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of x of the second kind of orders 0, 1, and n, respectively.

Switch to different names or don't `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: `y0()` and `yn()` are not standard library C functions.  Compiling to C99/C11 only should also be another way to avoid conflict.

Comment: genpfault thanku very much i didnt know that y0 and yn are actually functions i was using them as identifier what an error but thank you again

Comment: also if possible can you tell why my code after editing is not showing the line on the output screen i have renamed x0 as xi and yo as yi ,xn as xf and yn as yf its running fine but nothing is displayed on screen but when i dont take input from user then i am getting a line.